# Given $A=\{x \in \Bbb Q| 0<x<1\}$ check if the set is bounded , find $\max,\min,\sup,\inf$ if they exist

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

> Given $A=\{x \in \Bbb Q| 0<x<1\}$ check if the set is bounded , find $\max,\min,\sup,\inf$ if they exist.

---

I am practicing and I would like to know if what I am doing is correct.

given $x \in \Bbb Q$ we know that $x= \frac{m}{n}$ while $m,n \in \Bbb Z$ , $n \not=0$ and $m \not= n$ (although this is not needed because we can see that it is bounded simply because $0<x<1$) we get $0<\frac{m}{n}<1$ $\iff$ $0<m<n$ therefore it is bounded

- No minimum:

Assume by contradiction that there exists a minimum $minA=a$ so $a \in A$ according to minimum definition and $0<a<1$ according to density theorem between two rational numbers there are infinitely many rational numbers and $0<\frac{a}{2}<a<1$ from here we get that there is no minimum

- No maximum:

Same idea assume by contradiction that there exists a maximum $maxA=a$ so $a \in A$ according to maximum definition and $0<a<1$ yet again by density theorem there are infinite rational numbers between (Could I also say that because $a<1$ there is no maximum?)

- finding infimum:

let $x \in A$ and $0<x<1$, assuming by contradiction that $m=0$ is not infimum therefore there exists $m_1>$ which is a bound from below $A=(0,1)$, if $m_1>1$ then every element in $a \in A$ fulfills $m_1>a$ so it is not a bound from below if $0<m_1<1$ then according to density there is a real number $1>m_1>a>$ so $m_1$ is not a bound from below and $\inf A=0$

- finding supremum:

Same idea of the one above just slight differences .
let $x \in A$ and $0<x<1$, assuming by contradiction that $M=1$ is not supremum therefore there exists $M_1<1$ which is a bound from above and we know that $A=(0,1)$, if $M_1<1$ then every element in $a \in A$ fulfills $M_1<a$ so it is not a bound from above if $0<M_1<1$ then according to density there is a rational number $0<M_1<a<1$ so $M_1$ is not a bound from above and the supremum is $\sup A=1$

I hope my English is understandable thank you for any tips and help

Comment: For the maximum, instead of relying on the density theorem, I'd just point out that if $\alpha$ is rational and $0<\alpha<1$ then $\beta=(1/2)(1+\alpha)$ is also rational and $\alpha<\beta<1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you , so taking the average of $\alpha$ and $1$ puts it above $\alpha$ that's why it cannot be maximum ?

Comment: the first part about boundedness is unnecessary, as $0,1\in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: That's why $\alpha$ can't be a maximum. But $\alpha$ was arbitrary, so there can't be a maximum.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you , are the rest of the things I did correct? is there any other way you recommend on approaching ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing you've done looks incorrect!

Here is an alternative (direct) proof that $\inf A=0.$

> Since $A=\Bbb Q\cap(0,1),$ then $0$ is a lower bound of $A.$ To show it is the greatest lower bound, we show that $0+\varepsilon$ fails to be a lower bound for all $\varepsilon>0.$ Take any $\varepsilon>0.$ Since $0<\varepsilon,$ then $0<\min\{\varepsilon,1\}.$ Since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R,$ then there is some $q\in\Bbb Q$ such that $0<q<\min\{\varepsilon,1\}.$ Then $q\in\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)=A$ and $q<\varepsilon,$ and so $\varepsilon=0+\varepsilon$ fails to be a lower bound of $A,$ as desired.

A direct proof that $\sup A=1$ is very similar.

---

As an alternative overall approach, you might show:

- $A=\Bbb Q\cap(0,1),$ so is bounded as a subset of a bounded set, and in particular doesn't contain $0$ or $1$ as elements.
- $\inf A=0$ and $\sup A=1.$
- From the above, it follows immediately that $A$ has no minimum or maximum.